# xcode 8 entitlements mismatch error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, code-signing-entitlements

So I'm getting the famous entitlements mismatch error.[image]

It would seem that "The entitlements specified in my application's Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile."

What I want to know is how do I view the entitlements in my provisioning profile, and how do I view the entitlements in my Entitlements file so that I can compare them?

Out of the many answers to this question on stack overflow, none of them explain how to compare the Entitlements file to the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open your .mobileprovision and .entitlements file by using TextMate.
By doing so, you can compare both files and figure out what's different between them.

You can find your provisioning profiles in this path: /Users/_your_user/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Or via Xcode, through these steps:

1) opens Xcode, 2) Preferences (command + , ) , 3) accounts , 4) select your account , 5) select your team, 6) view details. A new window will open containing all provisioning profile installed, right click on the one you've been looking for and then "show in finder"

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I think I wasn't clear. I know how to open a file in a text editor. But to do that, I need to know where they are. My provisioning profile was generated by xcode, and don't know where it is on disk.

Comment: You can find your provisioning profile here: 1) opens Xcode, 2) Preferences (command  + , ) , 3) account , 4) select your account , 5) select your team, 6) view details. A new window will open containing all provisioning profile installed, right click on the one you've been looking for and then "show in finder"

Comment: I think you might have forgotten to paste the path

Comment: When I click on my team, there is no "view details" button that I can see. Can you post screenshot?

Comment: In that place there are two buttons: "download all profiles" and "manage certificates...". What version of xcode are you using?

Comment: I'm using 8.1, what's yours?

Comment: Its 8.1. I've seen other people mention the view details button, but I've never been able to find it.

Comment: Try this path: /Users/_your_user/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Comment: Thanks, that's the correct path. If you add that to your answer I'll upvote and accept

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was:

I unchecked "Automatically manage signing" and then check it on again. After that Xcode told me it would reset the settings to the default and after that it finally worked.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but you didn't answer the question. I want to know how to view my provisioning profile so that I can compare it to the entitlements file.

Comment: Please check this link, maybe this will be helpful for you https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1798/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not trying to distribute right now. I'm just trying to get a development build to work.

Answer (score 0):

Create all provisions along with app groups or any extension support in developer account.

Then come to Xcode and tick automatic signing for all targets, it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed my project, and the folder of the project files got changed too, so I changed the entitlement file path in `info.plist` and then it works.